# SwiftUI Open Push UIViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swiftui

I'm just trying out something with SwiftUI and want to start a project quais from scratch and build only with SwiftUI. Unfortunately, I am already failing the first thing. I want to create a UIViewController like effect by a button.
[View Xcode with a storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynCKY.png)

And as an end product it should look like this.
[Ansicht im Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4tFe.gif)

Unfortunately, I can not do that. I've read several tutorials, but it just does not work or I have the wrong approach.

How can that be done relatively easily? Maybe someone can help me? Or someone has a code example of something like that.

Comment: Can you edit your question with code that you’ve written so we can see exactly what you’ve tried? Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Based on the gif you provided, it looks like you’re trying to present a tab view modally when a button is pressed. Is that what you’re trying to do?

Comment: Honestly, "I want to create a UIViewController" means you are likely headed down *several* wrong paths, as they don't exist (except as a `View` if you use `UIViewControllerRepresentable`) in a `SwiftUI` stack (which isn't at all related to a `UIKit` stack). Please, accept this and then edit your question with *very much* more details! Include code, include behavior and desired behavior. It helps us to help you. Thanks!